# Docker Container Linking

Tags: docker

How do I link two containers in Docker? May I have a link for a guide or a tutorial in this regard?
I checked a tutorial but it didn't work till the end, it gave me errors in finding "sh"

Comment: Please post you docker compose or docker file

Comment: Do you mean two docker images? or you want two containers to communicate?

Comment: I am new to such thing, I mean it's my first try to link containers, so that's why I need a step-by-step tutorial to try to do so.

Comment: I want two containers to communicate

Comment: "Linking" is an obsolete Docker concept; you shouldn't need it today.  You might look at Docker documentation like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) or [Use user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) which run through the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this blog , it will work

https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers-69a4e5bf50fb